# Detect fluency from google speech api results

Tags: speech-recognition, speech, google-speech-api

I'm trying to determine the fluency of a speaker using google speech (to text) API.

So far I have found that the API (betav1) can show the time taken to speak a word ( its starting time and ending time ).

And from Wikipedia,

> Oral fluency or speaking fluency is a measurement both of production
> and reception of speech, as a fluent speaker must be able to
> understand and respond to others in conversation. Spoken language is
> typically characterized by seemingly non-fluent qualities (e.g.,
> fragmentation, pauses, false starts, hesitation, repetition) because
> of ‘task stress.’ How orally fluent one is can therefore be understood
> in terms of perception, and whether these qualities of speech can be
> perceived as expected and natural (i.e., fluent) or unusual and
> problematic (i.e., non-fluent)

I can see we can get the pause, repetition, etc from the API of a word. But relative measurement can be difficult as I can't find any standard values.

Is there any proper approach to achieve this? Can anyone give a guideline to detect the fluency from google API (or any other valid approach using some sort of open-source speech libraries or external software)

It's completely fine if I am going in completely the wrong direction, just need a proper guideline to achieve the feature.

Comment: try https://www.speechace.com instead

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev, oh crap. it comes a little late for us. we already implemented using google speech. but damn this would have been so easy :(

Comment: @SadiMahmud Can you pls ahre how you used Google speech to build a fluency test?

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev sheechace works only for native english speakers of US/UK

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the data you have. I'm not familiar with the google text to speech API. However, there are a few alternative options to achieve what you want depending on the structure of the data.

1. If the data is structured (i.e. a table of words and values corresponding to properties of those words), you could run a classification (or regression) algorithm such as random forest or multiple logistic regression to either estimate the degree of fluency (on a continuous scale) or a category of fluency (e.g. very disfluent, somewhat disfluent, normal, somwhat fluent, very fluent).
2. If the data is unstructured (e.g. a recording of a phrase) - then you could try a neural network in keras/tensorflow that aims to classify different phrases as fluent or disfluent.