# Detecting filler words in speech-to-text

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

I used Google Speech API to do speech-to-text conversion. However, it filters out filler words such as "uh, um, ah" etc. I there any way I can get the text including the filler words ?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50020796/detect-fluency-from-google-speech-api-results

Answer (score 0):

Use more flexible api like Kaldi http://kaldi-asr.org

Answer (score 0):

Use Amazon's Aws transcribe, though the accuracy of detecting filler words is very less in all Speech-to-text APIs, here you can detect filler words.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody's still looking for the answer to this question in 2022:

Rev AI's API supports well in detecting standard filler words. (You can also provide other custom words)